# Java Random.nextInt() behavior

Tags: java, random

I wrote this simple code just out of curiosity and encountered some behavior of the nextInt() method from the Java Random class that I don't quite understand. Can anyone help me to figure it out?

The program simulates a simple coin flipping. So as far as I understand the probability of the nextInt(101) for numbers less and greater than 49 should be equal.

But as long as I increase the number of iterations, the balance tends to get positive, for example after 100,000 iterations, I didn't get a negative number. Why does this happen?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int balance = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int result = random.nextInt(101);

        if (result > 49) {
            balance++;
        } else {
            balance--;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Player's balance = " + balance);
}
```

Comment: don't create a new Random object each iteration... you lose the randomness that way

Comment: @RobOhRob just checked it with a single instance of Random, the same happens.

Comment: Your random, as also said, is odd number of element, that is 101 numbers that can be created, [0..100].  Your assumption is almost right.  All element HIGHER then 49 is equal to all element LOWER then 49.  Your code doesn't test for this.  It test LOWER OR EQUAL.  A common fault.  `! a > b` isn't `a < b`, it is `a <= b`.
You should write `if (result > 49) { balance++; } else if (result < 49) { balance--; } else { /* equal 49, don't do anything */ }`.  Then you will get a result more equal to 0.
Or generate 100 numbers in range [0-99], then your code will work ( `.nextInt(100);`).

Comment: And move `Random random = new Random();`  out of the `for`-loop, so you don't create a new random variable for each loop.  That is as explained bad, as it will use up more memory, and possible "eat up" lots of random values if the implementation uses hardware random numbers, which it doesn't do.  But if you do this to fast, it will get serie of same "random numbers", as `Random()` object initializes from the current time.  So not so many random numbers are generated. Depending how fast your computer are, slower will generate more random-ness.. ;-)
(prev post, last sentence will _almost_ work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call `int result = random.nextInt(101)` which creates uniformly distributed integers in [0,100], which can take 101 different values. If you check `if (result > 49)` then you have 51 possible values ([50,100]) and in the else case you have only 50 values ([0,49]). Thus the result is more likely to be in the upper part. To fix it you can do `int result = random.nextInt(100)`.

Comment: better still, just use `random.nextBoolean()`

Comment: Yes, `if ( random.nextBoolean() )` will work, probably the best answer.  Also if one use the original code and realize that `! a > b` is *NOT*  `a < b`, but `a <= b`.  Thus if change the code to `if ( random > 49 ) { balance++; } else if ( random < 49 ) { balance--; }` will work.  As then `49` isn't counted, and we count numbers greater *OR* less then 49.

Answer (score 1):

you are testing 51 possibilities for a positive outcome and only 50 possibilities for a negative outcome.

- 100-50 = 51 possibilities
- 0-49 = 50 possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

If you have tried, `random.nextInt(99)`, result will be different, I got minus value many times.

The reason behind this is that `random.nextInt()` Method.
quoted from the JavaDoc.

```
 The algorithm is slightly tricky.  It rejects values that would result
 in an uneven distribution (due to the fact that 2^31 is not divisible
 by n). The probability of a value being rejected depends on n.  The
 worst case is n=2^30+1, for which the probability of a reject is 1/2,
 and the expected number of iterations before the loop terminates is 2.
```

Please see here [Random.java#nextInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)

Comment: No, that's not the reason behind that.  The JavaDoc is explaining a technical detail that guarantees that if you have `n` outcomes, each one has a `1/n` chance of occurring *even if `n` doesn't divide evenly into 2^31*.  What you're experiencing is the exact same phenomenon as in the question - your pool size (99) is odd so it can't be split into two equal sized subsets. If all outcomes occur with equal probability one of the subsets occurs more often than the other.